# Looking for a start point to use the new iOS7 features of Core Data

Tags: core-data, ios7

I've watched [WWDC2013's session 207](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/) ("What’s New in Core Data and iCloud"). Are there any sample projects to see how the new features should be used in a real world application (asynchronous setup, account changes and so on)? Are there any tutorials or sample projects to start from? Has anyone successfully implemented it so far?

Comment: No sample projects I have come across.  We are using the new capabilities and with the exception of WAL mode they seem fine, there are some strange quirks still so not sure this version will go for sale, although its being used daily internally, but we have tech savvy users.  We have a Mac version of the app as well as an iOS version and the Mac version has file management built in for keeping backups etc., just in case.  So far no corrupted files.

Answer (score 1):

In April 2014 Apple updated the documentation and sample code. See [iCloud Programming Guide for Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/UsingCoreDataWithiCloudPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013491-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

There is no official sample code yet and some of the documentation still seems to be outdated (specifically, Apples "iCloud Design Guide". However, at least one developer has published his own sample code on GitHub. You can find it here: https://github.com/mluisbrown/iCloudCoreDataStack